# Why does the enable-system-notifications flag no longer work in chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, notifications

I'm trying to get native/system notifications working on Chrome (so that they show up in the action center), but I can't get them work.

I've tried the `chrome://flags/#enable-system-notifications` flag, but it doesn't seem to do anything anymore. No matter what I set it to, Chrome uses its built-in notification system, and not the Windows 10 one.

Notifications for Chrome are turned on in the Windows settings app.

I'm using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 64-bit on Windows 10 20H2.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: There is no guarantee a flag like that is actually implemented.

Comment: I guess you're right... it's just really annoying that I'm not able to properly rely on notifications, because I don't see them if there's a native notification available. Plus the notification doesn't pop up in the action center, so if a notification pops up and disappears when I'm not there, I don't see it. Was hoping there was some solution...